# Spark Dynamic Allocation does not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am having the following conf for spark application

```
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=80
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=120 
--conf spark.default.parallelism=480 
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=480 
--conf spark.driver.cores=3 
--conf spark.executor.cores=3 
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=3072 
--conf spark.executor.memory=21G 
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=3072 
--conf spark.driver.memory=21G 
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=8g 
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer 
--conf spark.extraListeners=ch.cern.sparkmeasure.FlightRecorderStageMetrics 
--conf spark.sparkmeasure.printToStdout=true
```

but when I run the spark application only one executor is run
[image]

based on my understanding there should be at least 80 executors right?

Comment: 27 cores total and 3 cores per executor, how it could be 80?